# Java Integer object instantiation with parameters

Tags: java, integer

This question is a part of OCP test series .

```
> Integer i=new Integer(100_00);
```

I tried to understand how this works but so far i have only got this much that this is one of a message format . Please provide some clarity as to how we can pass a numeric value with a underscore . Pardon me if this is a simple concept but i am kind of anxious to know this .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Java allows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) numeric literals with `_` for better readability.

For example:

```
int i = 10_000;
float pi =      3.14_15F;
```

Comment: In other words, `10_000`, `100_00` and `10000` are all the same; they all mean "ten thousand".

Comment: Thanks Jigar and Kevin . Your answers combined answer this . So this is just for readability . After your code gets compiled, these underscores are removed in bytecode stream ?

Comment: The compilation process itself deals with the underscores.

Comment: I am sorry deals ?

Comment: correct, `int i = 100 `and `int i = 1_0_0 `compiles to same thing